# Set method for Java

Tags: java

I am new to java and I created a set method book reference number so it accepts only 3 characters. I tried my code below but it's not right.

```
public void setRefNumber(String ref)
 {
  System.out.println("hello " + ref());
      if(ref.length() ==3)
{
        return;
 }
  System.out.println("Fail...Your reference number mis too short"); 
}
```

Comment: what is **ref()** in you print statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    setRefNumber("123");
    setRefNumber("1234");
    setRefNumber("12");
    setRefNumber("aa"); //to show you that you are not checking if the passed parameter is even a number currently
  }

  public static void setRefNumber(String ref) {
    if(ref.length() >= 3) {
      System.out.println("hello " + ref);
      return;
    } else {
      System.out.println("Fail...Your reference number " + ref + " is too short");
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
hello 123
hello 1234
Fail...Your reference number 12 is too short
Fail...Your reference number aa is too short
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/E8MA/0)

Answer (score 0):

`ref` is a variable and not a method. So `ref()` should be `ref`.
Besides, you don't set a `ref` field in your current instance.
If 3 is too short according to the message in the output :

```
System.out.println("Fail...Your reference number mis too short");
```

you should do `<3` in the condition.
Generally , handling error cases at the beginning of the method or as soon as possible allows to separate error cases from nominal cases (fail fast principle).

Here an example :

```
private String ref;
public void setRefNumber(String ref) {
    System.out.println("hello " + ref);    
    if(ref.length() < 3){
      System.out.println("Fail...Your reference number mis too short"); 
      return;
    }
    this.ref=ref;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method returns without doing anything. Do what you have to do before return statement. Also if you provide both if and else part, you do not have to use return while your method type is already void.

```
public void setRefNumber(String ref) {
  // it could be null too
  if ( ref == null ) {
   System.out.println("Cannot be null);
   return;
  }
  System.out.println("hello " + ref);
  if(ref.length() == 3) {
    // set ref here
    System.out.println("Success");
    // return;
  } else {
    System.out.println("Fail...Your reference number is too short/long"); 
  }
}
```

And like others pointed it out. ref is variable not method. Use ref instead of ref().